# Momentum of an electron acting as a wave

Tags: waves, electrons, relativity, wave-particle-duality

Was working on a problem with electrons acting as waves in diffraction. Part of the question asked me to calculate the momentum of the electron. Since I was dealing with waves I used the following equation:

$h=pλ \implies p = h/λ$

Since $λ = v/f$ we can substitute that in, resulting in $p = hf/v$.

Substituting in the de Broglie $h = E/f$ into the above equation we get $p = E/v$. Since we're talking about electrons the only energy that the electron has is kinetic so we can substitude $E = 0.5mv^2$ into the equation giving us $p = 0.5mv^2/v = 0.5mv$.

I've repeat that, $p = 0.5mv$. Any 4th-grade physicist knows that momentum is $mv$ so on one hand, I have mv and on the other I have a derivation saying the momentum is $0.5mv$. Is there a mistake in my derivation I'm not seeing?

P.S: I noticed something a bit later. $p = E/v \implies E = pv = mv^2$. See any similarities between this and another infamous equation in the realm of relativity?

Comment: $E=hf$ applies to photons.  It is not valid for electrons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Since I was dealing with waves I used the following equation:
>   $$h=pλ \implies p = h/λ$$

This is fine.

> Since $λ = v/f$ ...

True for all waves, yes.

> ... we can substitute that in, resulting in $p = hf/v$.

This is okay, but we don't usually find people talking about the "frequency" of an electron matter wave.

> Substituting in the de Broglie $h = E/f$ ...

Ah, here's your problem.  The de Broglie equation has nothing to do with energy or frequency --- the de Broglie relation is $p = h/\lambda$.  The relation $E=hf$ is a result for massless particles, see below.

> ... Since we're talking about electrons the only energy that the electron has is kinetic ...

This is a reasonable statement for a free particle.

> ... so we can substitude $E = 0.5mv^2$

Nope, that's a nonrelativistic approximation muddled by a confusing notation.  The [relativistically correct statement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112344/44126) is
$$
E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2
\tag 1
$$
where $E$ is the *total* energy, including the rest energy, and the kinetic energy is $K = E-mc^2$.
For *massless* particles, the Einstein equation (1), the de Broglie equation $p=h/\lambda$, and the wave equation result $\lambda f = v$ combine to give the *result* $E=hf$. 
However for *massive* particles you find instead
\begin{align}
E^2 &= \left(\frac{hfc}{v}\right)^2 + (mc^2)^2
\\
K &= -mc^2 + \sqrt{\left({hfc}/{v}\right)^2 + (mc^2)^2}
\end{align}
which is much less helpful. Hence people don't talk much about the frequncies of matter waves.

Answer (score 13):

From Einstein's famous equation we have,

$E=mc^2$

From classical mechanics we have,

$E = \frac{mv^2}{2}$

Equate both of them (both are E, right?) and you'll get

$mc^2 = \frac{mv^2}{2}$

$c^2 = \frac{v^2}{2}$

All objects in the universe are moving at $c\sqrt{2}$

Yes, they are moving FASTER than light. Oh dear! Physics does not work!

**Do you notice the mistake?**

You cannot equate arbitrary equations with one another even if the quantity has the same sign and is of the same type.

$E = h\nu$ is an equation which describes the energy carried by an electromagnetic wave of frequency $\nu$

**Are electrons photons?**

No. How can you equate the kinetic energy of an electron with the energy associated with a photon of a particular frequency? Does that even make sense?

Comment: Wow, I was *this* close to downvoting you. Good thing I kept reading :)

Comment: According classical mechanics we have other types of energy also .