# Is Einstein's formula $E=mc^2$ the same as the kinetic energy formula $\dfrac{1}{2} mv^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, velocity, mass-energy

If the kinetic energy formula is the same as Einstein's formula then $E=mc^2=\dfrac{1}{2} mv^2$. Or, $\dfrac{1}{2}v^2=c^2$. What does this prove? Does it prove that $\dfrac{1}{2}$ of the velocity squared of a moving object is always equal to speed of light squared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$E=mc^2$ resembles kinetic energy formula?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112343/)

Comment: Please make at least some attempt to check whether your question has been asked before. In this case [it didn't require a very complicated search](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=einstein+kinetic+energy).

Comment: How can it *prove* that statement when it's obviously false? Is the half of your velocity squared equal to the speed of light squared? (which indicates that the formula is not the same)

Comment: @avito009 This answer [1] might help you in clearing some of your doubts regarding the "mass increase due to velocity". You seem to be misunderstanding the mass-energy equivalence as it appears from your answers to this question.

[1]: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133395/20427

Comment: Had you failed to notice that some objects move faster than others?  (I  can't have been speeding officer, my speed is always exactly the same as everyone else's!)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer.

Energy= mc2+ 1/2 mv2. Both the formulas arent equal but to get total energy we need to add both. Sorry guys my mistake. Any more insights to this? Maybe you can explain why add both these formulas.

Comment: This is an equation that takes into account both the kinetic energy and the mass increase due to motion, at least for low speeds. But how?

Comment: Can you explain why you have added these formulae?

Answer (score 0):

"This is an equation that takes into account both the kinetic energy and the mass increase due to motion, at least for low speeds. But how?"

Energy and mass are equal. So when we move an object very slow the v2 in the formula 1/2 mv2 is low so Energy is equal to this mass which is 1/2m*v2. this accounts for mass increase. Got it?

This 1/2m*v2 is nothing but the mass after moving. Since E=M (Energy equals mass).