# Electron Scattering Velocities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

So, I'm being taught about the many different types of scattering; one of these is electron scattering. In my notes, it says that the electrons are accelerated to high energies, of around 6 GeV.

After being curious of what velocities these electrons are travelling at, I decided to try and work it out:

- 6 GeV = 9.6x10<sup>-10</sup> J
- Assuming the kinetic energy of the electrons, $9.6*10^{-10} = \frac{mv^{2}} {2}$
- After making $v$ the subject, $v = \sqrt{\frac{2E_{k}} {m}} = \sqrt{\frac{2 * 9.6*10^{-10}} {9.11*10^{-31}}}$ = 4.59x10<sup>10</sup> ms<sup>-1</sup>

This sounds absurd, since the calculated velocity is much higher than the speed of light; as far as I'm aware, no object can have a velocity greater than this.

Can anyone spot any errors in my calculations/thinking etc? It's making me slightly confused.

Answer (score 1):

That the velocity comes out close to (or in your case even greater than) the speed of light is an indicator that you have to use the [relativistic formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation). As it is explained there in the limit of low energies, when the particles move slowly compared to $c$ the usual formula $T= mv^2/2 = p^2/2m$ is a very good approximation.

To make it short, the right formula to use is

$$E = \gamma m c^2$$

where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I suppose my error comes from my lack of knowledge; I haven't learnt about relativity yet. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: It's worth noting that [the relativistic expression is still correct at low speeds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112343/44126).

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the assumption of total energy is equal to kinetic energy. In this case,the electron has a kinetic energy and a rest energy. Remember $$E^{2}=(pc)^{2}+(mc^{2})^{2}$$