# What is the difference between $E$ in Einsteins theory of relativity, and $E_k$ in the equation to work out kinetic energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy

If $E=mc^2$, and $E_k=\frac12mv^2$, what is the difference between $E$ and $E_k$?

Comment: One is relativistic total energy (if $m=\gamma m_0$), and the latter represents the (classical) kinetic energy.

Comment: This is answered here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112343/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$E=mc^2$ resembles non-relativistic kinetic energy formula $E_K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112343/)